# Why, when writing python/tkinter gui code, is it apparently necessary to call tkinter.Tk before tkinter.Stringvar can be called?

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to submit additional information but kept getting the following error:
Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Paste your entire code here and then select all and press Ctrl+K to format as code

Comment: `tkinter.Tk()` creates a instance of `Tk()` which will be your main window for the project, without the `Tk()` there wouldn't be a main window

Answer (score 1):

It is because Tkinter is a wrapper around an embedded tcl interpreter. Creating an instance of `Tk` initializes this interpreter. Since `StringVar` instances and widgets must be created by and in the interpreter, they can't be created until the interpreter has been initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I suspected that TCL was at the base of this issue.